# LLVM Loop Invariant Code Motion (-licm) pass

Tags: loops, llvm, compiler-optimization, static-analysis

I have some simple C loop code, and I want to **simplify
it as much as possible**. Here is the original C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *foo(char *s)
{
    while (*s == 'a' || *s == 'b')
    {
        s++;
    }
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *s1 = argv[1];
    char *s2 = foo(s1);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried using `opt` with the `-licm` flag, which is supposed to:

> remove as much code from the body of a loop as possible. It does this by either hoisting code into the preheader block

But when I look at the loop body, I see that lines 21 and 22 are really **redundant**, as `%s.addr` did *not* change, and so lines 21 and 22 can be safely deleted, and instead of `%tmp3` we can use `%tmp1` from line 23
onward.

```
 13 while.cond:                                       ; preds = %while.body, %entry
 14   %tmp = load i8*, i8** %s.addr, align 8
 15   %tmp1 = load i8, i8* %tmp, align 1
 16   %conv = sext i8 %tmp1 to i32
 17   %cmp = icmp eq i32 %conv, 97
 18   br i1 %cmp, label %lor.end, label %lor.rhs
 19 
 20 lor.rhs:                                          ; preds = %while.cond
 21   %tmp2 = load i8*, i8** %s.addr, align 8
 22   %tmp3 = load i8, i8* %tmp2, align 1
 23   %conv2 = sext i8 %tmp3 to i32
 24   %cmp3 = icmp eq i32 %conv2, 98
 25   br label %lor.end
```

What am I missing? is there some other pass to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing that `%s.addr` is not invariant in the while loop. The loop invariant code motion optimization identifies expressions that do not change between iterations and try to lift them out of the loop. What you are looking for is something like common subexpression elimination. This optimization identifies repeated computation of the same subexpression and tries to remove all but one.
In my version of `opt` this optimization is enabled by the `-early-cse` switch.